# What does JpegMini use to animate the image comparison on the homepage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, jpegmini

Hopefully the title is clear. I'm talking about the large image comparison slider on the homepage of [JpegMini](http://www.jpegmini.com/main/home).

I've managed to identify it as needing three core files (written as they are named on the site):

- `jquery.min.js`
- `jquery-ui-1.8.14.min.js`
- `scripts-0135.min.js`

It's this last one I'm unable to find any information about so it may hold the secrets but I don't know.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never was able to determine the script used, in the end I searched the web and found a suitable alternative which came with good documentation. http://www.catchmyfame.com/2009/06/25/jquery-beforeafter-plugin/

Comment: Yes, this is the one we used on JPEGmini

Answer (score 1):

The `.imagePairs` elements have a mousemove event bound:

```
$('.imagePairs').data('events').mousemove[0].handler
```

is a function.

The code is apparent inside `scripts-0135.min.js`, but it is minified.

What you can do is parsing it through [jsbeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) and see if you can make something out of it. It will still have variable names which make no sense, so it will not be easy.

Looking at the code, it seems like they initialize it with `$('.imagePairs').myBeforeAfter`, which is most probably the function that handles the effect.